# how to produce a third normal form and BCNF decompositions

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, 3nf

I'm trying to produce a 3NF and BCNF decomposition of a schema. I have been looking at the algorithms but I am very confused at how to do this.

If I have my minimal cover say: `F' = {A->F, A->G, CF->A, BG->C)` and I  have identified one candidate key for the relation, say it is `A`. Then what exactly do I do?

I have been looking at examples, one which has the following:

```
F = {A → AB,A → AC,A → B,A → C,B → BC}
```

Minimal cover: `F′ = {A → B,B → C}`

And the final result was: `(AB,A → B), (BC,B → C)`.  How did they get to this?

Answer (score 1):

> If I have my minimal cover say: F' = {A->F, A->G, CF->A, BG->C) and I
>   have identified one candidate key for the relation, say it is A. Then
>   what exactly do I do?

F' is not a minimal cover: you have to combine A->F and A->G to A->FG

Even worth A cannot be a candidate key given F' since B does not belong yo the closure of A. A possible candidate key would be AB.

For 3NF you start with creating tables for each one of the dependencies in F', i.e.,

```
R1(A,F,G) R2(A,C,F) R3(B,C,G)
```

Next you check whether one of the tables contains a candidate key. Since B appears only on the left side of the dependencies, B should always be a part of a candidate key. The only table with B is R3 and it does not contain candidate keys (check it!). Hence, we add a new table R4 with a candidate key as attributes

```
R4(A,B)
```

Finally, we check whether the set of attributes of one of the tables is contained in the set of attributes of another table. This is not the case for our running example.

Hence, our 3NF decomposition is

```
  R1(A,F,G) R2(A,C,F) R3(B,C,G)  R4(A,B)
```

For BCNF you start with R(A,B,C,F,G) and look for BCNF violations.

For instance A->FG is a violation of BCNF because this dependency is not trivial and A is not a superkey. Hence we split R into

```
R1(A,F,G) and R2(A,B,C)
```

None of the relations obtained contains BCNF violations, so the process stops here.